# Change the radius of SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift

How can we change the radius of the SKShapeNode without recreating it? In the header file there is only an initialiser with circleOfRadius syntax.

Comment: There's no other option besides using the scale property.

Answer (score 7):

If you create the SKShapeNode with a path, you can change the path at any point later. Try this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        let location = theEvent.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        if let circle = node as? SizeableCircle { // clicking on an existing circle
            circle.radius = Double(arc4random_uniform(100))
        } else { // clicking on empty space
            self.addChild(SizeableCircle(radius: 100.0, position: location))
        }
    }
}

class SizeableCircle: SKShapeNode {

    var radius: Double {
        didSet {
            self.path = SizeableCircle.path(self.radius)
        }
    }

    init(radius: Double, position: CGPoint) {
        self.radius = radius

        super.init()

        self.path = SizeableCircle.path(self.radius)
        self.position = position
    }

    class func path(radius: Double) -> CGMutablePathRef {
        var path: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
        CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 0.0, 0.0, radius, 0.0, 2.0 * M_PI, true)
        return path
    }

}
```

The difference between this and scaling is that anything else that you set (e.g. line width, text child nodes, etc.) will *not* change unless you make them.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 4:

Essentially, you can launch an `SKAction` for `scaleTo` or `scaleBy` with a specific `TimeInterval` as a duration, anyway I've translate the Grimxn class to the latest swift in case you have to use it for other reasons:

```
class SizeableCircle: SKShapeNode {

    var radius: Double {
        didSet {
            self.path = SizeableCircle.path(radius: self.radius)
        }
    }

    init(radius: Double, position: CGPoint) {
        self.radius = radius

        super.init()

        self.path = SizeableCircle.path(radius: self.radius)
        self.position = position
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    class func path(radius: Double) -> CGMutablePath {
        let path: CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint.zero, radius: CGFloat(radius), startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(2.0*Double.pi), clockwise: false)
        return path
    }

}
```